# How to set custom dimension with Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have the following google analytics code that attempts to set a custom dimension `123456` and send it to analytics with the `pageview`:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){
 i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){(i[r].q=i[r].q||
 []).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)
 [0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)})

 (window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

 ga('create','UA-CXXXXX-1','domain.com');
 var dimensionValue='123456';
 ga('set','dimension1',dimensionValue);
 ga('send','pageview');
```

I have set up the custom dimension as per the [docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/customdimsmets#overview) (defined as a `session` level scope) however when viewing as a secondary dimension in the report no pageviews show.

The tracking code definitely works as pageviews without the secondary dimension show hits. Any ideas?

Comment: well you got anything on it . please add as answer i'm looking for the same . cheers